# The reason given for closing this question seems wrong

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99434/arduino-vs-microprocessor) was closed with the reason "This question does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope defined in the help center."

That I don't understand.  The OP wants to interface to a resistive touch screen using either an Arduino or a microprocessor.  That seems to be in the purview of "a specific electronics design problem" as described in the [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), just below the first paragraph.

There are certainly lots of other questions on this site re interfacing to an Arduino, so I can't see how that is an issue.

Granted, he has some misunderstandings on what a microprocessor (or microcontroller) is, which is covered in the answers.  His best bet, obviously, is to use an Arduino.

Comment: This was correctly closed as off topic (before the edit). It originally asked about who knew something, not any electronics concept. Yes I understand that asking something by starting with *"Does anyone know ..."* is all too common. However, we do engineering here where attention to detail matters. People need to learn to ask what they really want to know, and to stop and *think* about what they are actually saying. This sort of sloppy language is bad, here and in the real world, but at least here we can do something about it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You've got to be kidding me.... "I've got **standards** so being an smartass is OKAY!" Would you have said the same thing to his face? The question was not off-topic.

Comment: @W5VO  That was a *very low quality* question.  It's unfortunate that somebody had wasted 5 minutes on editing it.  It's a pity that it got reopened.

Answer (score 2):

That *exact* reason is what gets displayed when there are conflicting close reasons. In this particular case, Olin voted to close with the reason (and three other people agreed):

> Yes, lot's of people know the difference between a arduino and a
>   microprocessor. However, while actually discussing the difference
>   could be on topic here, discussing who knows what is not.

Which breaks from the prompt that you normally get with a custom off-topic reason which is:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about...

So congratulations, you managed to close a question because someone started off with "Does anyone know". I wonder how you would handle that situation in person?

---

Two other people voted for "Unclear what you're asking", so the system defaulted to the "safety" case:

> This question does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Pretty confusing to those reading the reason for closing, when the question clearly **is** about electronics design.  Meanwhile the question has been reopened, so I guess it's a moot point.

Comment: @tcrosley Well, this is really more about abusing the "Off Topic" reason, and then the side effects when the system believes that the question is 3/5 votes for "Off Topic".

Comment: Olin's reply "Yes, lot's (sic) of people know..." is as stupid and childish as replying "Yes" to the question "Do you have the time?"